# NSPredicate multi level filter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate

I am trying to search on `NSMutableArray` with two levels drill down with custom objects, I tried using `SELF` and `ANY` but no luck.

I have an `NSMutableArray` say `contentArray`
Content Array

```
contentArray
    {
     OBJECTA,
     OBJECTA
    }
```

Which has custom objects (`OBJECTA`), `objectA` in turn has a custom object called `Customer`

**OBJECTA:**

```
@interface OBJECTA : NSObject
{
    @property (strong,nonatomic)   Customer * selectedCustomer;

}
@end
```

**CUSTOMER:**

```
@interface Customer : NSObject

   @property(strong,nonatomic) NSString* Customer_Name;

@end
```

Now how I will be able to search `contentArray` for `Customer_Name` using `NSPredicate`?

Comment: `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.selectedCustomer.Customer_Name LIKE %@" searchNamed];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this way if you want to match exact name

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"selectedCustomer.Customer_Name LIKE '%@'", searchName];
```

If you want to check name contains than

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"selectedCustomer.Customer_Name CONTAINS[cd] %@", searchName];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"selectedCustomer.Customer_Name CONTAINS[c] %@", your_name_here];
NSArray *filteredArray = [contentArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```